# Opening a website on many computers simultaneously

Tags: windows-server-2008, website, internet-explorer

We have an ICT suite with 20 computers, and often teachers will all want the students to use the same website. Is there a utility which will allow me to open a website on multiple computers? At the moment I have to log all of the computers in, open IE and enter the address manually.

Thanks

Comment: Don't have time for a proper answer, look up IE Kiosk mode.  You'd configure that, set it as the replacement shell for `explorer.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

Psexec from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx can run a program on multiple computers quite easily.